# Session Start Keeps Firing in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I've created an ASP.NET web forms application and the `Session_Start` event in `Global.asax` keeps firing when my web app is running in production. I don't have this issue when running the app locally.

I put some logging code in the `Session_Start` event to see when it fires and in checking the log I can see that it is firing multiple times.

I am changing the `web.config` file when the user first logs in because I'm getting database and server information to create a connection string but that's the only time I'm touching `web.config`.

What can be causing the app to keep creating a new session?

I was previously using `inProc` mode for session state and would lose my session variables after about 10 minutes because of this issue, but now I switched to using `SqlServer` and the values are retained for the specified timeout time. However, in the Sessions table I can see new sessions are constantly being created when I'm the only one currently using the app. Also, when I use Chrome developer tools `ASP.NET_SessionId` isn't changing. So what are all these entries in the Sessions table and why does the `Session_Start` event keep firing?

Comment: Changing web.config while running is a very bad idea... it restarts the website, and then has to re-create the sessions. You can't store a per user connection string in web.config - if 2 users login at the same time they will both end up using the last connection string written.

Comment: If you're changing the web.config file, that would force the server to reload the application, invalidating any sessions, right?

Comment: Why does the connection string information have to go into the web.config? Can you gather the connection string information from the db and server and just use it directly in the application?

Comment: You may be able to use the ASP.NET Profile Properties to store per user information.

Comment: @DaleK That's a good point. This is my first big web project so I'm still learning some of the basics. I changed my connection string builder method to just modify a string with the values that I get from the user sign in and then store the connection string in a session variable to use throughout the app. Now that I'm not touching the web config file hopefully this resolves the issue!

Comment: @DaleK I'll also look into using profiles. However, I'm getting server and database values when the user logs in through their Microsoft account so I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Sounds like the session cookie isn't being updated in your browser. It's possible it has the wrong attributes (e.g. its domain or path doesn't match the URL) or your browser is set to reject cookies.  Or the cookie is being stripped by a proxy or module somewhere. Check the Network tab in Chrome tools to see if there is a cookie header being received.

Comment: @JohnWu - note that OP restarts app *before* session cookie has chance to be written by touching web.config - so what you said is pretty much should be the case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I modified my code to not touch the web config file at all and published to production but I'm still having the same issue. In fact I just ran a test - I didn't touch the code since 11:22 but looking in my log file "Session Started" four times at 11:33! I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: "7/22/2020 12:03:11 AM, Global.asax, Info: Session started." This just printed four times in the log file and I didn't even do anything in the app.